# Storing user authentication in Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When a user logs into my site:

```
Session["User"] = new User(Name);
```

To see if a visitor to a page is logged in:

```
if(Session["User"] != null) {
    //Session["User"].Name is logged in!
}
```

Is this secure? Does the client have any way of modifying the Session variables?

Comment: why don't you use the built in authentication systems?

Comment: Aside from Daniel's remark, you might have a look at session hijacking to get an impression how safe a session is and how to protect it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912167/session-hijacking-protection-in-asp-net

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't even know there was one, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392804/is-forms-authentication-more-secure-than-storing-user-identity-in-asp-net-sessio/19192471#19192471).

The short answer is: forms authentication is much more secure.